# Rest call for "Media Encoder Standard" in azure ?

Tags: rest, azure, azure-storage, azure-media-services

I'm using "Azure Media Encoder" to encode the video uploaded for streaming using below REST API call

```
GET https://wamsbayclus001rest-hs.cloudapp.net/api/MediaProcessors()?$filter=Name%20eq%20'Azure%20Media%20Encoder' HTTP/1.1
DataServiceVersion: 1.0;NetFx
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0;NetFx
Accept: application/json
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
Authorization: Bearer http%3a%2f%2fschemas.xmlsoap.org%2fws%2f2005%2f05%2fidentity%2fclaims%2fnameidentifier=amstestaccount001&urn%3aSubscriptionId=f7f09258-6753-4ca2-b1ae-193798e2c9d8&http%3a%2f%2fschemas.microsoft.com%2faccesscontrolservice%2f2010%2f07%2fclaims%2fidentityprovider=https%3a%2f%2fwamsprodglobal001acs.accesscontrol.windows.net%2f&Audience=urn%3aWindowsAzureMediaServices&ExpiresOn=1421675491&Issuer=https%3a%2f%2fwamsprodglobal001acs.accesscontrol.windows.net%2f&HMACSHA256=9hUudHYnATpi5hN3cvTfgw%2bL4N3tL0fdsRnQnm6ZYIU%3d
x-ms-version: 2.11
Host: wamsbayclus001rest-hs.cloudapp.net
```

I got a suggestion to use "Media Encoder Standard" instead of "Azure Media Encoder" to reduce the encoding cost. Is there any REST API call for Media Encoder Standard ?  I did't find any.

Answer (score 0):

```
GET https://media.windows.net/API/MediaProcessors HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose
DataServiceVersion: 3.0
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0
x-ms-version: 2.11
Authorization: Bearer
```

will return a list of all supported media processors which you can use. Select appropriate based on your job.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh973617.aspx is a Azure Media Services REST API reference page

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh973619.aspx contains various task presets for individual encoders